# Is it possible to include a String from a Java file in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm working on an old JSP project, and I have an issue where I have a Java file that has some static strings, and I want to pull those strings into a JSP file for usage.

In the Java file:

```
package path.path1.path2
public interface MyJavaStrings
{
   public static final FIRST_NAME = "Joe";
   public static final LAST_NAME = "Smith";
}
```

And then the JSP looks something like this:

```
<%@ page import = "path.path1.path2.MyJavaStrings" %>
<%@ taglib uri="jstl-core" prefix="c" %>

<%
   String firstName = MyJavaStrings.FIRST_NAME;
   String lastName = MyJavaStrings.LAST_NAME;
%>

<script>
   console.log(<%=firstName %>);
</script>
```

That's the overall approach I'm taking, but whenever I look at the console, it seems as if it's just logging nothing, so no value got passed in, but it isn't failing either. Is there a different approach to take?

Comment: `console.log(<%=firstName %>);` is this right?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I wasn't 100% sure. Is that the way to get java variables inside of javascript?

Comment: print the value from the scriplet tag

Comment: @ScaryWombat do you mean just doing something like console.log(firstName); ? I tried that, and it doesn't work for me either

Comment: No, forget about javascript, just output it from your JSP.  Also see the link that this question was closed with.